# Stack empty TensorArray

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using TensorArray a lot, but in some cases I might get empty TensorArray, but stacking it throws error:

```
boxes_pixels = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32,size=1,dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False, name='boxes_pixels')
boxes_pixels = boxes_pixels.stack()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([boxes_pixels]))
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray boxes_pixels_5_16430: Could not read from TensorArray index 0.  Furthermore, the element shape is not fully defined: <unknown>.  It is possible you are working with a resizeable TensorArray and stop_gradients is not allowing the gradients to be written.  If you set the full element_shape property on the forward TensorArray, the proper all-zeros tensor will be returned instead of incurring this error.
     [[{{node TensorArrayStack_4/TensorArrayGatherV3}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-0a1c9b0047d8> in <module>
      3 
      4 with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
----> 5     print(sess.run([boxes_pixels]))
```

What can be done to overcome this ?